# How to access different elements of pointer here

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

Here the string is splitted and pointed by `array`. Now I want to access these pointers. How can I do that?

**Also**, is it possible to initiate the **number of elements of `array`** based on the number of strings we are going to get from `strtok`. Like here we will get three strings `abc,qwe,jkh` so program will initiate 3 elements of `array`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
char string[]=  "abc/qwe/jkh";
char *array[10];
int i=0;

array[i] = strtok(string,"/");

while(array[i]!=NULL)
{
   array[++i] = strtok(NULL,"/");
   printf("%s",*(array));
    
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `printf("%s",*(array));` to `printf("%s", array[i]);`.

Comment: array[0], array[1], array[2], etc. You can even use a variable, as in `array[i]`

Comment: For your updated question, you could check the length of the string before creating the char* array and divide by two? Assuming every other character is a separator that is the maximum number of substrings possible, right?

Comment: @mlibby Its like I want to be precise if possible. Say I have a string ```This is a string```. So here I need to prgram to initiate 4 elements of ```array```.

Comment: You have two options. Either run the strtok loop once keeping count, then allocate memory for the array, then run it again storing the pointers in the array. OR allocate the maximum amount of memory possibly needed, run the strtok loop once (keeping track of the number of matches), then allocate a new array and copy from the oversized one, then free the oversized one.

Comment: Another option would be to use a data structure designed to be flexible in the number of elements it contains, like a linked list.

Comment: @mlibby running the ```strtok``` loop twice is not helpful as I tried it before posting the question itself

Comment: Your best bet is to stop using an array and switch to a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems. 1 - `printf("%s", array[i]);` otherwise you are just printing the first pointer in the array each time. 2 - reverse order of operations in loop or `i` is incremented too soon. 3 - need to prevent writing past the end of the array.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char string[] = char string[] = "abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr/stu/vwx/yza/bcd/efg/hij";
  char *array[10];
  int i = 0;

  array[i] = strtok(string, "/");

  while (array[i] != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    i++;
    if(i < 10) {
      array[i] = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about to check *i* to break the loop before to write out of the array ? Also to print a newline each time or at the end

Comment: *i* must be check **before** to access `array[i]`